# como puedo guardar datos y despues mostrarlos junto a con una imagen en un datagridview c# desde mysql

Tags: mysql, c#, datagridview, visual, studio

estoy realizando una applicacion en visual studio c# en la cual hay varios campos como codigo de producto nombre y foto del producto.
segun voy guardando dichos datos en base de datos me gustaria que se mostrarán en un datagridview pero guardar las imagenes y despues mostrarlas no me está saliendo.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (txtCodigo.Text == "" || txtNombre.Text == "" || txtPrecio.Text == ""
              || comboFamilia.Text == "familias")
        {
            popup p = new popup();
            p.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
        {
            string query;
            conectar();



            query = "INSERT INTO  articulos  (codigo, nombre,familia, precio) VALUES( '" + txtCodigo.Text + "', '"
            + txtNombre.Text + "', '" + familia + "', '" + txtPrecio.Text + ", "  + txtCodigo.Text + "');" ;

            
            
               
            
            
            
            MySqlCommand cmd=null;
            try
            {
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
                if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("data inserted");

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("data not inserted");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            
            
         
            desconectar();
            //limpiar text boxes y demas contenido
            dtgvOfertas.DataSource=null;
            txtPrecio.Text = "";
            txtNombre.Text = "";
            txtCodigo.Text = "";
            lblPath.Text = "";
            
            comboFamilia.SelectedIndex=-1;
            pictureBoxPreview.Image = null;
            cargadatos();
        }
        
        
        



    }
```

en el codigo falta el campo foto pero deberia ponerlo para guardar la foto en formato blob o cual sea que me aconsejen. ahora les muestro el codigo de cargar los datos en datagridview, donde el texto esta perfectamente pero si intento cargar una imagen no puedo no se muestra.

```
private void cargadatos()
    {
        
        try
        {
            conectar();
            
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT codigo, nombre, familia, precio" +
                " from articulos  ORDER BY familia, codigo asc;", conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            dtgvOfertas.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
            dtgvOfertas.RowTemplate.Height = 120;
            dtgvOfertas.AllowUserToAddRows=false;
            da.Fill(table);
            dtgvOfertas.DataSource = table;
            dtgvOfertas.AutoResizeColumns(
                            DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
            desconectar();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        
        
    }
```

muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Por lo general se suele guardar los archivos en algua ruta de tu proyecto y no desde la base de datos, en tu base de datos lo que podrías almacenar para localizar esa imagen puede ser la ruta o algún identificador que permita saber a tu aplicación que tienes una imagén guardada en alguna carpeta de tu aplicación, guardar las fotos en blob no creo que sea una buena opción

Comment: una vez las guardo en una ruta de mi proyecto como puedo mostrarlas adecuadamente en el datagridview? porque cargo todos los datos obtenidos de mysql pero en cada fila deberia introducir la imagen